# Convert PHP array into Key => Value Array

Tags: php, arrays

Total PHP Noob and I couldn't find an answer to this specific problem.  Hope someone can help!

$myvar is an array that looks like this:

```
Array (  
 [aid] => Array (  
  [0] => 2  
  [1] => 1  
 )  
 [oid] => Array(  
  [0] => 2  
  [1] => 1  
 )  
)
```

And I need to set a new variable (called $attributes) to something that looks like this:

```
$attributes = array(
 $myvar['aid'][0] => $myvar['oid'][0], 
 $myvar['aid'][1] => $myvar['oid'][1], 
 etc...
);
```

And, of course, $myvar may contain many more items...

How do I iterate through $myvar and build the $attributes variable?

Comment: this question is ambiguous, you should provide a bigger example set...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `array_combine()`

This will give expected result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Usage:

```
$attributes = array_combine($myArray['aid'], $myArray['oid']);
```

Will yield the results as requested.

Comment: how it is useful here can you expalin

Comment: $attributes = array_combine($myvar['aid'], $myvar['oid']);

Comment: This was it!  Thanks so much!  I still dont totally understand how its working, but I'll dig in deeper to see.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this if I understood the question correct

```
$attributes = array();
foreach ($myvar['aid'] as $k => $v) {
    $attributes[$v] = $myvar['oid'][$k]; 
}
```

Comment: Iteration like this is a waste of cycles and effort, and a bottleneck for very large array sets. The built-in array* functions are much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clear. what you mean by "And, of course, $myvar may contain many more items..." there is two possibilties

1st. more then two array in main array. like 'aid', 'oid' and 'xid', 'yid' 
2nd. or two main array with many items in sub arrays like "[0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 3"

I think your are talking about 2nd option if so then use following code

```
$aAid = $myvar['aid'];
$aOid = $myvar['oid'];

foreach ($aAid as $key => $value) {
  $attributes['aid'][$key] = $value;
  $attributes['oid'][$key] = $myvar['oid'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can itterate though an array with foreach and get the key and values you want like so

```
$attributes = array() 
foreach($myvar as $key => $val) {
   $attributes[$key][0] = $val;
}
```

Comment: this is the same as `$attributes = $myvar`

Comment: Should be `$attributes[$key] = $val[0];` for what the OP wants.

Comment: @blair your right i chanched my answer to reflect this change